# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \Big[\sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \Big]= \,?$

Tags: limits

Can you help me to calculate this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Big[\sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \Big]= \:?$$

I don't have idea how to calculate it.